# How do I disable a github workflow which is triggered by another one and do not affect the upstraem workflow?

Tags: github-actions, workflow

I have two github workflows A and B, B is triggered by A with the `workflow_call` way, so A -> B. This may be two jobs rather than two workflows. How can I disable job B without affecting A on Github UI or somewhere else? So that B can be disabled separately form A.

I tried write `workflow_run` way to change them into two workflows rather than two jobs in one flow, but don't know how to pass some information then.
Is there a perfect way to achive my needs?